# facebook uses cookies to know what sites we are browsing?

Tags: facebook, cookies

A while back in college I remember someone said that facebook makes use of cookies on our machine to track what websites we are browsing.

I thought a cookie is essentially an encrypted random string stored(if you allow) in your browser which the server also has a copy of server-side. The server uses this string as a key to store the state of your browsing session.

I cannot figure out how you can use the cookie mechanism to track a client's browsing when they are not visiting your site.

Can someone explain?

Answer (score 0):

Ask the NSA?

They're normally quite good at that